# Cannot install "caret" package

Tags: r, r-caret

I am unable to install the `caret` package in R. It seems that there is an issue with installing the `recipes` library on which it depends.

```r
install.packages("caret")
```

The message I get:

```r
also installing the dependencies 'ipred', 'recipes'


  There are binary versions available but the source versions are later:
        binary source needs_compilation
ipred   0.9-11 0.9-12              TRUE
recipes 0.1.16  0.2.0             FALSE
caret   6.0-86 6.0-90              TRUE

  Binaries will be installed
package 'ipred' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
package 'caret' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\Jason\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpQ9hRYY\downloaded_packages
installing the source package 'recipes'

Warning message in install.packages("caret"):
"installation of package 'recipes' had non-zero exit status"
```

Comment: `"installation of package 'recipes' had non-zero exit status"` gives a hint. Please try to install package `recipes` and check the errors.

Comment: Try: `install.packages("recipes", type = "binary")`.  This will download the binary package and skips the version which needs to built.

Comment: Sometimes `install.packages("recipes", dependencies = TRUE)` helped me in simialr situations.